# Python regex replace space from string if surrounded by numbers, but not letters

Tags: python, regex

My input variants as strings:

```
'12345 67890'
'abc 123'
'123 abc'
'abc def'
```

My aim is to remove the space if found between the characters if characters from both sides are digits, but not letters. I was considering using the re module, perhaps re.sub() function, or something similar.

Desired output:

```
'1234567890'
'abc 123'
'123 abc'
'abc def'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `regex` with lookahead and lookbehind:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', '', '12345 67890')
'1234567890'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', '', 'abc 123')
'abc 123'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', '', '123 abc')
'123 abc'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', '', 'abc def')
'abc def'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', '', '123 abc 1234 456')
'123 abc 1234456'
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need regex for this

```
if all(part.isdigit() for part in data.split()):
    data = data.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Wow... `translate`'s a bit heavy here... `replace` should be fine :)

Comment: What if data is `'12345 67890 abc'`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex:

```
re.sub('^(\d+) (\d+)$', r'\1\2', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex to do what you want:

```
re.sub(r"(?P<digit_before>\d)\s(?P<digit_after>\d)",r"\g<digit_before>\g<digit_after>",s)
```